# asyncio and streamlit concurrent read from multiple subprocesses

Tags: python, python-asyncio, streamlit

I want to start multiple subprocesses from a python streamlit app, then concurrently read from their stdout while they are running and print it to the app. The processes are started upon user decision, i.e. there is a button that adds a process to the pool. I have tried to implement this idea using asyncio like so:

```py
import asyncio

import streamlit as st

# persist the event loop across app rebuilds
try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
except RuntimeError:
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

if "running_processes" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.running_processes = {}
# start with 3 processes initially
st.session_state.processes = [2, 3, 4] if "processes" not in st.session_state else st.session_state.processes


async def start_process(proc_number):
    job = ['bash', '-c', f'while true; do echo "Running process {proc_number} at $(date)"; sleep {proc_number}; done']
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*job, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    return proc


async def logger(process):
    std_out = process.stdout
    while True:
        text = await process.stdout.readline()
        st.write(text)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)


if st.button("add process"):
    st.session_state.processes = st.session_state.processes + [max(st.session_state.processes) + 1]


async def main():
    for p in st.session_state.processes:
        if p not in st.session_state.running_processes:
            st.session_state.running_processes[p] = await start_process(p)

    await asyncio.gather(*[logger(p) for p in st.session_state.running_processes.values()])


asyncio.run(main())
```

The resulting app runs fine for the initial three processes, but as soon as I press the button to add a process, I get a runtime error: `RuntimeError: readuntil() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data` stemming from the `text = await process.stdout.readline()` line in the logger coro.
So I guess that somehow multiple readers get attached to the same subprocess, but I cannot figure out why this is happening or how to prevent it.